# Is there a way to create a temp table that overrides itself everytime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that loads data into a temp table and then retrieves it. Is there a way to make my temp table override itself when I try to run the query again instead of running into the problem of "#(temptablename) already exists"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't try to use a temp table like that - what should happen if you are running your query more than once at the same time? You wouldn't want it to crash by nuking itself...

Comment: If the temp table is not a global (#temp_table vs ##temp_table) you should be able to run it in multiple sessions without external impact.

Comment: Question is not clear or it has been over complicated! BTW, do you mean "Overwrite" or "Override"? If you mean "Overwrite", there is no overwrite on TABLE creation, you need to drop and create or you should use it assuming it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if the temp table already exists and drop it each time you run the script, before loading data.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.temp_table','U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.temp_table
GO
/*
 your script here
 --the table can be re-created using SELECT ... INTO
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table variable instead.  The main drawback is you have to define the structure; you can't use `SELECT ... INTO` to create the table variable.  You have to declare the table structure and use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
DECLARE @TempContacts TABLE
(
   Id        INT,
   FirstName VARCHAR(100),
   LastName  VARCHAR(100),
   Email     VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @TempContacts
SELECT 
    Id, 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    Email 
FROM Contacts
WHERE Id = @ContactId
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a reasonable argument for dropping your temp tables in your script. Theoretically SQL Server deletes the table when it goes out of context. Practically speaking it doesn't hurt to do this and it can, but not always, hurry up the garbage collection process. I typically also check at the top of a script (although NOT at the top of a procedure).

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temp_table', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp_table;
GO
CREATE TABLE #temp_table ([field] [int]);
-- work with #temp_table
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temp_table', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp_table;
GO

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps worth considering a [table variable](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-table-variables).  If you're running a more recent version of SQL Server, performance will probably be comparable with a temporary table.

Example (from above link)

```
declare @TableVar table (   NewPK int identity(1,1),    CustomerID nchar(5) NOT NULL  )

Insert Into @TableVar (CustomerID) Select   CustomerID From Customers

Select  Top 5 * from    @TableVar
```